# How to escape special char in vimwiki, a plugin of vim

Tags: vim, escaping

For example, I want to write the following content:

> $VAR can be reached by "$VAR"

But When I write it in vimwiki and turn it to html, it looks like:

```
\(VAR can be reached by "\)VAR"
```

because $ is a special char!

How can I escape the special char in wimwiki without using {{{ and }}}.

---

I have already read:

[Issue 62:  How to escape special char?](https://code.google.com/p/vimwiki/issues/detail?id=62&q=escape)

[Code Environments and Escape Mechanisms](https://code.google.com/p/vimwiki/wiki/NewEscapes)

but it didn't help!

Answer (score 0):

find the file "html.vim" in autoload\vimwiki

Change(line 323):

```
  return '\('.s:mid(a:value, 1).'\)'
```

To:

```
  return '$'.s:mid(a:value, 1).'$'
```

this will break inline math function, hope this will help you!